# How to hide framelayout dynamically in android

Tags: android

I want to hide framelayout dynmically in android, How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

provide an id attribute to your frameLayout by defining it in xml file as:

```
android:id="@+id/someID"
```

and in code, write following:

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.someID);
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You can also use

> View.INVISIBLE

which means the element will be still there.

Comment: Wow, just before me, almost the same comments :-)

Comment: I actually want to react regarding your comment 

"you can use INVISIBLE also instead of GONE"

I just wanted to point out the difference between the two. When using GONE the frame tends to disappear completely from the UI, while when using INVISIBLE, the frame gets indeed invisible but the UI still shows its empty place where it should be displayed.

Answer (score 6):

Change the visibility like this:

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById (R.id.your_id);
layout.setVisibility (View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE, depending on what you exactly want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide or show views using [setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).